# Early exit for the rules

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using stanford nlp library. 
I have a file which contains 1000 of rules. 
As of now for a given text it goes through the all the rules. 
So, lets say I have Rule 1 .. Rule 100. And for a given input Rule 2 was matched. The search does not stop here. It looks for all the rules.

Is there any way, if a rule is matched, then it stops the search instead of looking at all the rules always?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by using a `break` statement, so you'd have, in pseudocode:

```
rule = 0;
while (ruleNotFound) {
    if (rule > totalNumRules) 
    {
        // searched all rules but could not find it
        return false;
    }
    else if (checkRule(rule)) 
    {
        // found
        ruleNotFound = false;
        theRule = rule;
    }
    rule++;
}
```